# Extract objects from ArrayNode to ObjectNode with Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

I can't seem to find a solution to this anywhere, wondering if it is achievable.

My input is like the following:

```
{
    "Table": {
        "Row": [
            {
                "Order1": {
                    "Date": "foo"
                }
            },
            {
                "Order2": {
                    "Date": "foo"
                }
            },
            {
                "Order3": {
                    "Date": "foo"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is this:

```
{
    "Table": {
        "Order1": {
            "Date": "foo"
        },
        "Order2": {
            "Date": "foo"
        },
        "Order3": {
            "Date": "foo"
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially just get rid of the `ArrayNode` which is wrapping my objects.

I tried the following but can't figure out how to get the field name of the objects i.e. "Order1", "Order2" etc. to populate my new `ObjectNode`.

```
  protected ObjectNode arrayToObjects(ArrayNode input) {
    final ObjectNode result = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode();

    input.forEach(node -> {
        result.set("???", ((ObjectNode) node).deepCopy());
    });

    return result;
  }
```

The question marks is where I am confused, I can't seem to understand how to get the field names as I said above, below is a screenshot of the debug on the loop, the information is there but I can't seem to figure out how to unwrap it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add all properties from each item into `result` `ObjectNode`:

```
protected static ObjectNode arrayToObjects(ArrayNode input) {
    final ObjectNode result = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode();

    input.forEach(node -> node.fields().forEachRemaining(entry -> result.set(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue())));

    return result;
}
```